# Add class using data-option-value - Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to add selected class using data-option-value. If I click enable 1 its redirect to other page in that page I want to find which anchor tag has same data-option-value then I have to add class selected.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Home page -->
<a href="services/" data-option-value=".tab-1431326167-1-34">Enable 1</a>
<a href="services/" data-option-value=".tab-1431326167-2-16">Enable 2</a>
<a href="services/" data-option-value=".tab-1431326787790-2-7">Enable 3</a>


<!-- Other page -->
<a class="soft-bg-icons" href="#filter" data-option-value=".tab-1431326167-1-34"><span>Active 1 Content</span></a>
<a class="soft-bg-icons" href="#filter" data-option-value=".tab-1431326167-2-16"><span>Active 2 Content</span></a>
<a class="soft-bg-icons" href="#filter" data-option-value=".tab-1431326787790-2-7"><span>Active 3 Content</span></a>
```

Comment: You forgot to show us your current JS code to work on.

Comment: Yes. Because its not working. I have tried more than 5.

Comment: Anyway, show us what you tried so far. Maybe you are close to achieve it, or maybe we could work on your current code.

Answer (score 1):

for me you have 2 ways:

1. use **#hashtag**
2. use **querystring**

to send the `data-option-value` to an other page.

You can add to `<a>` `href` the `data-option-value` like **hash** or **query string** when you click on it and take it in the other page.

A simple example:

### homepage

```
$(function(){
     $("a").on("click",function(e){ //change selector to be more focused on your menu
         e.preventDefault();

         //if u use #hashtag way
         var _url = $(this).attr("href") + "#/class/" + $(this).data("option-value");

         //if u use query string way
         var _url = $(this).attr("href") + "?class=" + $(this).data("option-value");
         location.href = _url;
     });
});
```

### Lending page

```
$(function(){
    //if u use #hashtag way
    _mth = location.hash.match(/\/class\/(.*)/);

    //if u use query string way
    var _mth = location.href.match(/[?&]class=([^&]*)/);

    if(_mth) $("#page a[data-option-value='"+_mth[1]+"']").addClass(_mth[1].replace(".",""));
});
```

Remind to removes the code of the way you not follow.

### Note

**#hashtag** way generates a url like: */otherpage.html#/class/.tab-1431326167-1-34*

**Query string** way generates a url like: */otherpage.html?class=.tab-1431326167-1-34*

The **#hashtag** way needs to redirect to a page different by homepage (with different link).

;) try

Comment: Tried but no luck. I think i missed something. Anyway thanks for your time.

Comment: take a look to your browser console! :) and tell me if there are some errors. 
Are you sure to have included jquery libs?