# What does the data-option-value attribute do?

Tags: html

I am looking at the code for a gallery page. It is able to filter the type of media displayed (video, image, etc) and as far as I can see, it does this with the data-option-value attribute.

I cannot find any documentation explaining the functionality, application or anything else really about the data-option-value attribute.

Any help in explaining what this attribute is, what it does or how it assists in filtering the displayed media would be helpful.

Here is the code:

```
 <ul class="nav nav-pills sort-source" data-sort-id="gallery" data-option-key="filter">
                    <li data-option-value="*" class="active"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-th"></i> <span>Show All</span></a></li>
                    <li data-option-value=".images"><a href="#"><span><i class="fa fa-image"></i> Images</span></a></li>
                    <li data-option-value=".videos"><a href="#"><span><i class="fa fa-video-camera"></i> Videos</span></a></li>
                    <li data-option-value=".links"><a href="#"><span><i class="fa fa-link"></i> Links</span></a></li>
                    <li data-option-value=".sliders"><a href="#"><span><i class="fa fa-desktop"></i> Sliders</span></a></li>
                </ul>
```

Here is one of the code for one of the images in the gallery:

```
<li class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 grid-item gallery-grid-item links format-link">
                        <a href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank" class="media-box"> <img src="http://placehold.it/600x400&amp;text=IMAGE+PLACEHOLDER" alt=""> </a>
                    </li>
```

Comment: This may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30165044/add-class-using-data-option-value-jquery

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Anything starting with `data-*` is a custom HTML attribute that the author added to the HTML element to do something with it in JS.

Example:

`<div id="mydiv" data-width="500" data-content="Hello World" data-favoritecolor="green"></div>`

In short, you'll have to take a look at the JS, search for `getAttribute("data-option-value")`

Comment: And you can access the data-* value with the `dataset` keyword: `document.getElementById('mydiv').dataset.content --> "Hello World"`